# How to print the output of a bunch of dataframes? Help me improve my code

Tags: python, function, loops

I am trying to improve my python skills.  What can I do to make my code more efficient?  I have 10 datasets in k_frames, how can I set them each to a new dataframe and print the output.

I just copied and pasted the code x10 times (facepalm.jpg)

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame(k_frames[0])
df0.head()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(k_frames[1])
df1.head()

df2 = pd.DataFrame(k_frames[2])
df2.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to flatten the list of data frames into a single one -- use `pd.concat()`:

```
import pandas as pd

# ** defines a list of data frames called `k_frames` **

big_df = pd.concat(k_frames)

print(big_df.shape)
print(big_df.head())
```

You can then use whatever criteria define the different data frames (e.g. the values in some column) to print subsets of the big one.

Note: in case you use R, this does the same thing as `do.call(rbind, k_frames)`.

Or you could just loop over the list and print the head of each one:

```
for df in k_frames:
  print(df.head())
```

Comment: I am using python.   see the pd.dataframe

Comment: right of course, the answer is also python — just pointing out that concat is the python equivalent of the do.call/rbind idiom in R :)

Comment: is there anyway to use a loop in the case i want x10 seperate dataframe?

Comment: well if you have a list of dataframes, then they already are separate -- looks like you're already able to refer to them individually, e.g. as you do with `k_frames[0]`. it's usually better to have a list of elements than a large number of global variables referring to elements of the list